# Cannot find some header file (chicken.h)

Tags: compiling

I've exhaused all of my linux-fu (ubuntu 14.04) with this one. Essentially I want to have a play with the chicken implementation of scheme which compiles lisp to c

getting that far is fine but then compiling the c code gets me the error:

```
fatal error: chicken.h: No such file or directory
```

This file does indeed exist since the output from whereis chicken yields:

```
chicken: /usr/bin/chicken /usr/bin/X11/chicken /usr/include/chicken /usr/share/chicken /usr/share/man/man1/chicken.1.gz
```

my PATH variable has:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/include/chicken
```

and the output from env | grep PATH is:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/include/chicken
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
DEFAULTS_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.default.path
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/include/chicken
LD_LOAD_PATH=/usr/include/chicken
MANDATORY_PATH=/usr/share/gconf/ubuntu.mandatory.path
```

(where I've tried defining LD_(LOAD,LIBRARY)_PATH myself)

I'm still getting nowhere. Any ideas (I believe this is just an issue of telling gcc where to look for stuff but I haven't found the solution yet)?

Comment: If you solved your problem yourself, please [answer your own question](/help/self-answer) and accept it. Don't put the answer in your question!

Comment: ah ... sorry about that  ... answer provided (though I have to wait 2 days to accept it)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit. Solved by defining C_INCLUDE_PATH** (though fixing the auto-generated c compiler errors is going to be harder than telling gcc where to find its headers :/)